# Is it possible to listen for when a user cancels a Notification in Android?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-notifications

I'm interested to know when a user cancels a Notification from by application - is this possible? I'd like to listen for the event and then stop a service that runs in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any way to see if notification was deleted by user. You can make notification "persistent" - it can't be cleared - and start some action when user clicks on it.

Comment: I'm currently making it ongoing, but for some reason the Service gets cancelled sometimes when the screen is off, and then the Notification gets messed up.

Comment: Just write cancel notification code in `onDestroy` of your service

Answer (score 0):

You know that we append a **PendingIntent** in notification, so by using that intent we can launch an activity which may close the service and then call **finish()** on itself to go away. The entire process might be fast enough that a user may not notice any hiccup

Comment: That only works if the user presses on the notification. If it's cancelled, your suggestion will have no effect.

Comment: make your notification ONGOING would not allow it to be cancelled and the only thing user can do with it is to click it. Once clicked, you can do your magic

Comment: Yes, that would be the sensible approach for an ongoing service.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a PendingIntent sent when the notification is cleared explicitly by the user.
Please, take a look over here:  [Notification.Builder setDeleteIntent (PendingIntent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29)